# parse dns response when there are multiple NS records

Tags: java, dns, nameservers

Hello I am doing an assignment for school which requires you to build your own DNS CLient using java without using any existing libraries.
I figured out how to parse the response but there is an error when are multiple records in the Answer section.

```
public void processResponse(DatagramPacket packet) throws IOException{
    DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(packet.getData()));
    din.readShort(); //Transaction ID
    din.readShort(); //Flags

    int questions = din.readShort();
    int answers = din.readShort();
    int authorities = din.readShort();
    int additional = din.readShort();
    int recLen = 0;
    while ((recLen = din.readByte()) > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < recLen; i++) {
            din.readByte();
        }
    }
    din.readShort(); // Record type for question
    din.readShort(); // Class for question

    //ANSWERS
    //Just looping for one answer here
    for(int i=0;i<1;i++){
        din.readShort(); // Record name for Answer
        String response = "";
        int typeOfRec = din.readShort();
        din.readShort(); // Class for answers
        int ttl = din.readInt();
        short resLength = din.readShort();
        switch(typeOfRec){
        //A
        case 1:{
            response+="IP\t";
            String ip = "";
            for (int j = 0; j < resLength; j++ ) {
                ip+=("" + String.format("%d", (din.readByte() & 0xFF)) + ".");
            }

            response+=ip+"\t"+ttl;
            System.out.println(response);
            break;
        }
        //NS
        case 2:{
            String ip = "";
            response+="NS\t";
            while ((recLen = din.readByte()) > 0) {
                byte[] record = new byte[recLen];

                for (int j = 0; j < recLen; j++) {
                    record[j] = din.readByte();
                }

                ip+=new String(record, "UTF-8");
                ip+=".";
            }
            response+=ip+"\t"+ttl;
            System.out.println(response);
            break;
        }
        //CNAME
        case 5:{
            response+="CNAME\t";
            break;
        }
        //MX
        case 15:{
            response+="MX\t";
            break;
        }
        default:{
            break;
        }
        }
    }        
}
```

This is the function that finally processes the response packet to get the required data. However, when I run this code the response is only 
NS  ns-358.awsdns-44.   86399 the .com is missing

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to read up on how names are encoded in DNS wire format. Particularly how they are compressed. Section 4.1.4 of RFC 1035 will be a good place to start.